# Each iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm so frustrated seeing this error in my console. I had placed the key attr within my map. But why am I still seeing this?

http://pastebin.com/qKzMjCZ4

I've checked each of my iterated DOM, couldn't spot the problem. I really need some help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide us with a [mcve], rather than posting a link.

Comment: @TomFenech the code is too much to be shown here.

Comment: But not all the code is needed to replicate the issue, right? This may need some time for you to build, but an MVCE definitely would ease debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a lot of code, and pretty hard to finde mistakes. I didn't saw any items without key, so i thought problem somewhere in `key={obj.id}`. If `obj.id` undefined you can get this error. I advise you change this key to `i` or `index` that you send vith function argument.

I strongly advise you refactor your components, it's pretty obvious you get errors and can't find it with this mess.